# How can I stop JsDoc from ignoring my documentation comments?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I'm attempting to generate javascript documentation using jsdoc(http://usejsdoc.org/), but I'm having little luck. All my comments are being ignored. How can I get all my comments visible in the generated html?

```
define(function() {
    /**
     * Enum for tri-state values.
     */
    var eventTypes = {

        /** Comment 1 */
        Example1 : {name:"1", dataFormat:{
        }},

        /** Comment 2 */
        Example2 : {name:"2", dataFormat:{
            successCallback:function(){}
        }},

        /** Comment 3 */
        Example3 : {name:"3", dataFormat:{
            successCallback:function(){}
        }}
        };
    return EventTypes;
});
```